# How is this camera settling done?

Tags: unity, camera

For clarification: I don't need to know how to rotate the camera. 
What I'm asking instead is how the movement of the camera AFTER the mouse move is calculated (the "slow fade out"). I've tried a lot, but it never looks right to me.

The question:

I have uploaded a video [here](https://youtu.be/SfDJ9xvB7zw).

This video shows a camera settling behaviour.

In this video, the mouse pointer is moved swiftly from left to right.

The camera however does not abruptly start moving to the other direction, instead it settles in the previous direction before going to the other direction.

I would like to know how this is settling is done.
I have tried really much to recreate this behaviour:

Taking into account the overall speed until the next zero mouse movement, fading out the last non-zero mouse movement, just anything that I could think of.

Could anybody tell how he thinks this could be done?

Comment: Look into [Cinemachine](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/cinemachine-79898), its a package from Unity that has the ability to achieve the behavior you are interested in.

Comment: You might want to add what you have tried and why it did not work, this would help give answers that are more adequate to your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this rotation done?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167913/how-is-this-rotation-done)

Comment: @GaryHoliday No, this question here is more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Vector3.Lerp`? i.e. Lerping your current position to the target position calculated by the mouse movement.

Lerp is short for linear interpolation. In this case you'd move part way to the target. The final parameter is what portion of the total distance you want to move (in this case 50%). Lowering this would get a slower camera feel. There's also `Vector2.Lerp`, if you're doing a 2D game.

```
Position = Vector3.Lerp(Position, TargetPosition, 0.5F);
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

*Note: I don't use Unity*

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. What I don't understand (if I look at the video) is how it's calculated that the camera still swings to the right while some more and becomes slower while the mouse pointer is already moving the left.

Comment: Try changing the acceleration of the camera instead of the position? That would make sense if you want the camera to keep going.

Comment: I'm setting the position of the camera directly using the mouse position. The camera itself doesn't have an acceleration. Or perhaps I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I will improve my question to make the problem better to be understood.

Comment: I don't use Unity, so I can't really help you any more, sorry.